# Python: Split a string by "/" slash symbol

Tags: python, split, latitude-longitude

I have a lat/lng string:

`"31.20/121.36"`

How do I split it by the "/" symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.split()` function in order to cut it into two parts and it inserts them into a list.

```
text = "31.20/121.36"

print(text.split("/"))
```

This outputs `['31.20', '121.36']`.